# Manage Sqitch migrations when deploying different branches

Tags: postgresql, schema-migration, sqitch

When we deploy to our Testing environment with Sqitch, the migrations run and all is well. However, when we have to test a different code branch, the Sqitch migrations aren't rolled back. What I'm looking for is an idea of how others are solving this problem. For example, if I have a migration that creates a table `my_table`, and then deploy a migration from a different branch, Sqitch gets too confused to move forward.

Reason for branch change: we have features using our `develop` branch, and hotfixes being applied to `master` (I know; we're going to change that). Swapping over to test a hotfix caused all of this mess.

We considered having a Jenkins job to run a `sqitch revert` and have the user supply the migration to roll back to, but we want to eliminate the manual step.

How do you manage migrations when having to switch code branches?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the purpose of [sqitch-checkout](https://sqitch.org/docs/manual/sqitch-checkout/)